# Lookup field from Access displays numeric value instead of text in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have the following line in my VBA code

```
SELECT Creator,Responsible FROM MyTable
```

Both columns refer to a lookup value in a different table. This other table has 3 values: ID, Name, Login Name. I assume the numeric value I get in Excel is the unique ID. I want to display the Name instead of the ID. Access shows me the Name column, but Excel is showing me the Unique ID column. I need the Name column in Excel as well.

Comment: Means nothing without knowing what the data is being taken, I'd imagine changing to "select name from tablename"

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Both the columns are taken from table "MyTable". Both values are a lookup value in a different table with 3 columns. I get the 1st column of that table if I get the data in excel ( the Unique ID ), while I get the second column ( name ) in Access. I also need that second column ( Name ) in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lookup field stores one value but displays a different value.  That may seem convenient at times.  But it can be very confusing when you actually get the stored value instead of the "looked up" value.

In your case, it seems that `Creator` contains a number, and the lookup feature retrieves the `Name` from a row in some other table whose `ID` value matches the `Creator` number.

You will need to do a similar lookup in your query:  Create an `INNER JOIN` between `MyTable` and the other table.  Then the query can show you the `Name` associated with the stored `Creator` number.

```sql
SELECT m.Creator, o.Name
FROM
    MyTable AS m
    INNER JOIN OtherTable AS o
    ON m.Creator = o.ID
```

It sounds like you will also need to apply that strategy to the `Responsible` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried the above in vba but an error shows up: "No value given for one or more required parameters." When I run this query in Access, It  prompts me for 2 values. The result of the query is 2 columns, with the value that I entered in the prompt, with the same amount of rows as there is in MyTable. I see the logic in the inner join , but I can't get my head around the reason access demands values for the columns.

Comment: When Access doesn't recognize something in your query, it assumes that something must be a parameter.  Often that is a result of misspelled field names.  What does Access think the parameter names are?  The parameter input box contains the name of the parameter.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I had translated my column names to make it easy to understand. I changed everything except "o.name"... My column name was "naam", which is name translated to my language. I've wasted your time on this one